# Inverse function must have a discontinuity

Tags: analysis, functions, continuity

We observe the following function:
$$g:[-\pi,\pi)\to S^1,\;\; \alpha \mapsto e^{\alpha*i} $$
We have that $S^1$ is compact and $[-\pi,\pi)$ is not compact. I am now confused to understand and show that the inverse function $g^{-1}$ must have a discontinuity.
Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

It is not exactly as you describe. You need to specify what are the open set in $[-\pi,\pi)$ and in $S^1$.

Note that in the case of $[-\pi,\pi)$ the open sets are generated by the intervals $(a,b)\subset [-\pi,\pi)$ and the sets $(a,\pi)\cup[-\pi,b)$, and not only by the intervals $(a,b)\subset [-\pi,\pi)$.

Taking the topology on $[-\pi,\pi)$ generated by those sets, your map $g$ has indeed a continuous inverse.

PS: It is more often used the map $$h:[-\pi,\pi]\to S^1,\;\; \alpha \mapsto e^{\alpha*i}, $$
with the endpoints $-\pi$ and $\pi$ identified (which corresponds to indicate the former sets).